# Oracle Report taking forever, but the query runs fast

Tags: sql, oracle, report

My query takes about 3-5 seconds to run. When I run the report, a simple summary of a few columns it takes 25-30 minutes!! It is a Group Left report. I've tried playing around with the query, and I've tried handling the grouping in the query with no luck.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Is the report doing a lot of additional calculations, sums etc? Try doing all the calculations in the database if possible. Also, if this is in the E-Business Suite as a Concurrent Request, turn on a SQL Trace at the Concurrent Program and view the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the query being executed within a stored procedure? If yes try executing the SQL without passing the variables through an SQL stored procedure.

If there is a difference in time it takes to execute, try some optimizations like for example removing parameter sniffing (create local variables from within the stored procedure which contain copies of the variable values being passed through the stored procedure). These can give you an indication if the query requires optimization.

Comment: The query is being run from the report directly. I don't have permissions to create stored procedures...that's another issue

Comment: What you can do is analyze the query with the SQL Profiler for MS SQL, or on oracle you can use the dbms_profiler. You can see what resources are being used and in what sections of the query. That way you can notice if any particular sections need optimisation.

If you do not have permissions on your user account to alter procedures etc, than this is something that needs to be moved to the DBA.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, sometimes queries that return a lot of data will appear to run fast from a tool like Toad or SQL Developer, but when you try to get all the rows, then you hit the real overall performance of the query.

So perhaps your query returns a lot of rows and all that time is spending doing all the i/o.